# Pgfplot filled contour-sharp edges

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to get a smooth filled contour like the following one:
[image]

Similar to this.(ignore the line plots inside)

For this purpose, I use `contour filled`. However, I am not getting a smooth filled contour. See this plot below:
[image]

If you click on the picture and see, you can notice sharp edges. How do I avoid this to get smooth plot like the first picture?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{colormaps} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\pgfplotsset{every tick label/.append style={font=\large}}
\pgfplotsset{every axis/.append style={label style={font=\large}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colormap/jet,
    colorbar,
     colorbar style={ ytick={0.25,0.125,0,-0.125,-0.25} },
    %view={0}{90},
    x=9 cm,
    y=7 cm,
    z=0 cm,
    point meta min=-0.25, point meta max=0.25,
    xlabel=$z$, ylabel=$r$, xtick={0,0.2,0.4,0.6,0.8,1,1.2,1.4,1.6,1.8,2}]
    \addplot3[%z buffer = sort,  
    %patch refines=2,
    %patch,
    %patch type = bi,
    shader=interp,
    contour filled = {number=500,labels={false}}
    ] file {Vz.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The corresponding data [here](http://pastebin.com/C2Ey62mY)

Comment: I believe `patch type=bilinear` is the best that you can get here. Note that `500` contour levels are probably the same as if you write `surf,shader=interp` right-away. The only way to increase the quality in `pgfplots` is to add increase the plot resolution, I suppose.